# Saved many images to vector but they do not display

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I used `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` from the `<windows.h>` library to load up all the images of a folder to a vector. This saved all the images to the vector `images` but when I want to perform any operation on the vector such as simply wanting to display them it gives an unexpected operation and forces me to break running of code.

Here is my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;


vector<Mat> images;

hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\test\\*", &FindFileData);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{

    do {

        images.push_back(imread(FindFileData.cFileName , 0)); 



        } while( FindNextFile(hFind,&FindFileData));
}

//int vectorsize = (sizeof(images)/sizeof(Mat));

namedWindow("meh" , CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("meh" , images[3]);
    waitKey(0);

/*for(int x = 1; x < 8; x++)
{
    namedWindow("meh" , CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("meh" , images[x]);
    waitKey(0);
}*/

/*vector<Mat>::iterator it;

for (it = images.begin(); it != images.end() ; it++) {
    imshow("myWin", (*it));
    waitKey(0);
}*/

FindClose(hFind);
return 0;
}
```

As can be seen I tried processing the vector with an iterator, but it gave the same error at `imshow`.

Then I used `sizeof` to find total elements in vector but that failed (as the vector size parameter returned `0`)

Then I picked a random image from vector and tried to display it but got same error at `imshow`.

`EDIT:` I would like to not that the test folder contains 8 images, but the loop runs 10 times. This is because the first and second files in the directory are `.` and `..` (This shows up when printing the names with `cout`) Can this be the reason causing the break? If so, how can I work around it?

Comment: `Mat m = imread(<random image file name>, 0);
imshow("meh" , m);`
Does this work?

Comment: @MichaelSh yes it works, I have all the libraries installed and working..

Comment: Mostly likely looking problem is the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile code. You do realise that (a) cFileName is just the file name not the full path, and (b) you must skip directories including the '.' and '..' pseudo directories that every directory contains.

Comment: Have you tried using pointers: `vector<Mat*>`, `vector<>` does reallocations periodically that trigger constructions and copying of `Mat` classes...

Comment: Using `sizeof` on a vector is completely wrong, go back to using `size()` and then figure out why it is returning zero.

Comment: @john I added the edit to my original question at the same time as your comment :), so is there a way to skip  ``.`` and ``..``? I did notice loop running 10 times whereas I only have 8 images.

Comment: Not just pseudo directories; **all** directories, as they will show up in your list as well. If you want to search for specific file types, add the extension (*.png) for example. And yes there is a way to skip "." and "..": check for them and don't append a `Mat` if those are the names returned.

Comment: @ipunished Like this `if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0) { /* it's a directory */ }`

Comment: Alright I got it sorted out. The problem was with FindFileData.cFileName as it was only returning the name of the file and not the complete path to file, which imread needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I got it sorted out. The problem was with `FindFileData.cFileName` as it was only returning the name of the file and not the complete path to file, which `imread` needs.

I solved that problem by using `strcat` and concatenating the path of folder with the file name found.

`images.push_back(imread((strcat(loc,FindFileData.cFileName)) , 0));`

ofcourse the string loc needed to be cleared every time as it would not work for the next loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do in your case an `!m.empty()` check to see if the image you have pushed back is correctly loaded.

For the EDIT part: you can find file on "C:\test\*.jpg". That will skip "." and ".." (and other non-image stuff), too.

(I think there was also a Microsoft syntax "C:\test\*.jpg;C:\test\*.png" for multiple extensions, but I am not sure about that.)

Comment: Alright I got it sorted out. The problem was with ``FindFileData.cFileName`` as it was only returning the name of the file and not the complete path to file, which ``imread`` needs. Thanks

Comment: Np, Im sorry that I could not be much of a help here.